# recuperar DateTime no MySQL entre a data atual

Tags: mysql, sql

No meu banco de dados tenho 2 campos: "data_inicio e data_fim".
A partir de um DateTime atual, preciso selecionar todas as datas que estejam no intervalo em que date_time >= data_inicio AND date_time <= data_fim.
Eu fiz a seguinte query e não funcionou. (considerem date_time como se fosse '2014-10-14 17:44:00') Obrigado!

```
SELECT * FROM campanha WHERE data_inicio <= '2014-10-14 17:44:00' AND data_fim > '2014-10-14 17:44:00';
```

Comment: Onde está o datetime atual na sua query?

Comment: '2014-10-14 17:44:00'

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a `data_fim` como `>=`. Da forma que você está fazendo, a query exclui todas as datas que são menores ou iguais que `2014-10-14 17:44:00` e do conjunto que restou, filtra os registros onde a `data_fim` é maior `2014-10-14 17:44:00`, ou seja, nenhum registro, pois os que sobraram são todos menores ou iguais que isso.

Ex.: 
`SELECT * FROM campanha WHERE data_inicio <= '2014-10-14 17:44:00' AND data_fim >= '2014-10-14 17:44:00';`

Comment: "UPDATE campanha SET estado = :estado_novo WHERE estado = :estado_atual AND data_fim >= now() AND data_inicio <= now()";
Essa é a query original. Funcionou perfeitamente, eu é que analisei de forma errada os resultados.